MYSY2 Git will not let me type when I try to enter my GitHub username
Recently I installed Git from MYSY2 in order to improve a Python library I use, but after cloning it and committing the changes I made, when I tried to push it - Git asked me for my GitHub username, but it doesn't actually let me type anything in when it does this, I literally cannot enter any text though the keyboard or otherwise, it just will not except any text! and does so just when it needs me to enter something.
This happens when I am using the MYSY2 Bash terminal or the Windows Command Prompt
I am using Windows 10.
[USER]@DESKTOP-D8JQH20 MSYS ~
$ cd /c/Users/[USER]/OneDrive/Documents/test1/TkinterWeb

[USER]@DESKTOP-D8JQH20 MSYS /c/Users/[USER]/OneDrive/Documents/test1/TkinterWeb
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    tkinterweb/tkhtml/win_amd64/Tkhtml30.dll
        modified:   tkinterweb/tkhtml/win_amd64/pkgIndex.tcl

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        tkinterweb.egg-info/
        tkinterweb/__pycache__/
        tkinterweb/tkhtml/win_amd64/Tkhtml30g.dll

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

[USER]@DESKTOP-D8JQH20 MSYS /c/Users/[USER]/OneDrive/Documents/test1/TkinterWeb
$ git push
Username for 'https://github.com':

That line at the bottom is where it won't let me enter any text - no characters will appear if I try.

MSYS2 git is known to be unusably slow anyway, even MSYS2 developers themselves don't recommend using it. Any reason why you're not using the normal git for windows, by adding it to PATH?

@HolyBlackCat I am unaware of MSYS2 Git being unusably slow, do you have a reference for the developers saying that? The reason I used MSYS2 Git is that I already have MSYS2 installed so found it simpler and more efficient to just use pacman -S git  than install a new software that might take up more space.

E.g. here: https://www.msys2.org/docs/git/ The normal "Git for Windows" should also handle the auth better, by opening a github login window in a browser.

Please don't add "solved" to the title or the solution to the question. Instead post an "answer" below and click a checkmark next to it to mark your question as solved.

I solved it by installing Git Credential Manager as a standalone application - by downloading the .exe file.

I generally use SSH instead of HTTPS to connect to my GitHub repo and it doesn't have this problem.  It doesn't prompt you for a password when it pushes, and instead authenticates you by talking to your SSH agent, which has your SSH key loaded.

In your repo's .git/config file, change https://github.com/ to git@github.com.
In your MSYS2 shell, run eval $(ssh-agent).
Type ssh-add your_prive_key_file and enter the passphrase for your key, if there is one.

If you don't like doing this process for every shell you open up, another idea is to set $GIT_SSH to point to plink.exe from PuTTY, and use pageant.exe from PuTTY to hold your keys.

I tried that and it said $ ssh -T git@github.com Hi [USER]! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access. and it still did the same - asked me to fill in the username but didn't let me.

What does the prompt say when it asked for your username?  Does it still say "https" in it?

$  git config --list user.name=Zamy846692 user.email=133600041+Zamy846692@users.noreply.github.com credential.helper=cache 
